# How to use tf.contrib.seq2seq.simple_decoder_fn_inference API

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I did not understand the parameters that needed to be passed into the API call to   `tf.contrib.seq2seq.simple_decoder_fn_inference` in Tensorflow 1.0
for building the inference block for a Seq2Seq Attention mechanism RNN.

Can someone explain, in detail, what each parameter of this function call means and is supposed to do?

The link to the documentation is here :
[tf.contrib.seq2seq.attention_decoder_fn_inference()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/attention_decoder_fn_inference)

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation?

Comment: The link to the documentation is here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/attention_decoder_fn_inference

Comment: Could you be more specific on what is not clear in the existing documentation?